# Navigation dropdowns overlapping can't get z-index correct

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I am having issues with dropdowns. 
I have some JS that will change the position of the dropdown if it is going to hit the edge of the window. It moves it to the other side of the parent dropdown. The problem is that the dropdown overlaps the root dropdown and the z-index is off.

I've tried adjusting the z-index on everything I could think of without any success. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid container-nav">
            <div class="container container-wo-pad">
                <div class="header-home">                       
                    <div class="site-title">                                 
                        <a href="/"><img class="logo" src="">
                        <h1>Site</h1></a>                                
                    </div>                         
                </div>
                <!-- navigation object : U Navigation Items -->
                <div class="nav">
                    <div class="navControl">
                        <a class="nav-btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Navigation</a>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav-root">
                        <li class="has-sub nav-root-item">
                            <a href="">LinkLinkLinkLink <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                            <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub">
                                    <a href="">Link <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                                    <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-sub">
                                    <a href="">Link <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                                    <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="">Link</a></li>   
                                <li><a href="">Link</a></li> 
                                <li class="has-sub">
                                    <a href="">Link <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                                    <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-sub">
                                    <a href="">Link <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                                    <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-sub">
                                  <a href="">Link <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                                  <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                  <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>  
                                <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link</a></li>                        
                            </ul>
                        </li>                    
                        <li class="has-sub nav-root-item">
                            <a href="">This one <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                            <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                <li class="has-sub">
                                  <a href="">Then this one <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                                  <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                  <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li class="has-sub">
                                          <a href="">Link <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                                          <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                          <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                            <li><a href="">Link </a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
                                          </ul>  
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="has-sub">
                                          <a href="">Last One <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                                          <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                          <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                            <li><a href="">LinkLinkLinkLinkLink</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                          </ul>  
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>
                                <li><a href="">Link Link Link Link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                    
                        <li class="nav-root-item"><a href="">Link</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-root-item"><a href="">Link</a></li>                            
                        <li class="has-sub nav-root-item">
                            <a href="">Link <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                            <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                <li><a href="">Sub link 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Sub link 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Sub link 3</a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub">
                                    <a href="">dropdown <span class="show-carrot">&#9662;</span> </a>
                                    <span class="open-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus open-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <ul class="dropdown sub-drop">
                                        <li><a href="">Sub link 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Sub link 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Sub link 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">Sub link 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
.container-nav {
      background-color: #00bcd4;
      margin-top: -1px; /* compensate for when alert isn't there */
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .nav .navControl {
      display: none;    
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .open-icon {
      float: right;
      padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    .nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .nav li {
      /* margin-left: -4px; */
      display: block;    
      position: relative;    
      z-index: 1;
      font-size: 16px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .nav a {
      padding: 15px 20px;
      display: inline-block;    
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .nav a:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .nav-root li a {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .nav .dropdown {
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .nav .dropdown li {
      margin: 0;
      display: block;
    }

    .nav .dropdown a {
      padding: 15px 20px;
      border-right: 0;
      margin-right: 10px;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #b9afaf;
    }

    .nav .dropdown li:last-child a {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    .has-sub .open-icon {
      border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .sub-drop {
      display: none;
      background-color: #0097A7;
    }



    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
      .site-title {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .site-title h1{
        font-size: 33px;
      }        
      .search {
        width: 100%
      }
    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    }
    @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
      .site-title {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .search {
        width: 100%
      }
      .nav .navControl {
        display: block;
      }

      .nav-root {
        display: none;
      }

      .show-carrot {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 600px) {
      .site-title {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .search {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .search-field {
        width: 50%;
      }
      .logo {
        width: 50px;
      }
      .home-container {
        margin-top: -34px;
      }

      .container-no-pad {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .container-nav {
        height: 189px;
      }

      .nav {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .nav-root {
        padding-left: 0;
        display: block;
      }

      .nav-root li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .nav ul {
        border: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      .nav li {
        /* margin-right: -4px; */
        display: inline-block;
        border: 0;
      }

      .nav a {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .nav a:hover {

      }

      .nav .dropdown {
        display: none;        
        background: #80DEEA;         
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
      }

      .nav .dropdown li {
          display: block;
      }

      .nav .dropdown a {
          margin-right: 0;        
          white-space: nowrap;
      }
      .nav .dropdown a:hover {
          background: #00bcd4;
      }

      .nav span {
        display: inline;        
        position: relative;
        left: 5px;
      }

      .nav a:hover + .dropdown,
      .nav .dropdown:hover {
        display: block;
      }

      /* desktop hover sub dropdown show */
      .nav a:hover + span + .dropdown {
        display: block;
      }

      .dropdown .dropdown {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
      }

      .sub-drop {
        display: block;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
      }

      .open-icon {
        display: none !important;
      }
      .show-carrot {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
        NAV dropdown z-index
    \*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .dropdown {
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown {
      z-index: 2000;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown {
      z-index: 3000;
    }

    .dropdown li {
      z-index: 1001;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown li {
      z-index: 2002;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown li {
      z-index: 3003;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.dropdown').parent().hover(function() {
    var menu = $(this).find("ul");
    var menupos = $(menu).offset();

    if (menupos.left + menu.width() > $(window).width()) {
        var newpos = -$(menu).width();
        menu.css({ left: newpos });    
    }
    });
});
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/west4me/ctxp4f3u/3/)

Image of the issue:
[image: Menu overlap]

Comment: Have you tried giving the elements you set the z-index a position like for exaple position:absolute? I can't test it right now but i know that missing position can mess with the z-index

Comment: Yes I looked at the position and made sure it was set.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you have a lot of unnecessary css styles in there, but mainly you are missing a z-index on that last ul ( which I updated with the class newStyle ).

https://jsfiddle.net/ctxp4f3u/4/

```
.newStyle {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so I was able to find something in your styling here some changes but jsfiddle has other modifications

```
.container-nav {
      background-color: #00bcd4;
      margin-top: -1px; /* compensate for when alert isn't there */
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .nav .navControl {
      display: none;    
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .open-icon {
      float: right;
      padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    .nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .nav li {
      /* margin-left: -4px; */
      display: block;    
      position: relative;    
      font-size: 16px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .nav a {
      padding: 15px 20px;
      display: inline-block;    
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .nav a:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .nav-root li a {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .nav .dropdown {
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .nav .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown li {
      margin: 0;
      z-index:8888
      display: block;
      background-color:#00bcd3
    }
    .nav .dropdown a {
      padding: 15px 20px;
      border-right: 0;
      margin-right: 10px;
      width:80%;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #b9afaf;
    }

    .nav .dropdown li:last-child a {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    .has-sub .open-icon {
      border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .sub-drop {
      display: none;
      background-color: #0097A7;
    }



    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
      .site-title {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .site-title h1{
        font-size: 33px;
      }        
      .search {
        width: 100%
      }
    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    }
    @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
      .site-title {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .search {
        width: 100%
      }
      .nav .navControl {
        display: block;
      }

      .nav-root {
        display: none;
      }

      .show-carrot {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 600px) {
      .site-title {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .search {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .search-field {
        width: 50%;
      }
      .logo {
        width: 50px;
      }
      .home-container {
        margin-top: -34px;
      }

      .container-no-pad {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .container-nav {
        height: 189px;
      }

      .nav {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .nav-root {
        padding-left: 0;
        display: block;
      }

      .nav-root li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .nav ul {
        border: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      .nav li {
        /* margin-right: -4px; */
        display: inline-block;
        border: 0;
      }

      .nav a {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .nav a:hover {

      }

      .nav .dropdown {
        display: none;        
        background: #80DEEA;         
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
      }

      .nav .dropdown li {
          display: block;
          width:200px;
      }

      .nav .dropdown a {
          margin-right: 0;        
          white-space: nowrap;
      }
      .nav .dropdown a:hover {
          background: #00bcd4;
      }

      .nav span {
        display: inline;        
        position: relative;
        left: 5px;
      }

      .nav a:hover + .dropdown,
      .nav .dropdown:hover {
        display: block;
      }
      .nav .dropdown .dropdown:hover
      {
        display:block
      }

      /* desktop hover sub dropdown show */
      .nav a:hover + span + .dropdown {
        display: block;
      }

      .dropdown .dropdown {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
      }

      .sub-drop {
        display: block;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
      }

      .open-icon {
        display: none !important;
      }
      .show-carrot {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
        NAV dropdown z-index
    \*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .dropdown {
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown {
      z-index: 2000;
    }
/*
    .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown {
      z-index: 9999;

    }

    .dropdown li {
      z-index: 1001;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown li {
      z-index: 2002;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown li a {
      z-index: 9999;
    }
     .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown li {
      z-index: 9998;
      display:block
    }*/
```

please view jsfiddle example link below, hope it helps.

[Example On jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilaponce/4d4pdejo/5/)